# Non-Piecewise Representation for Binary Switching Function

Tags: functions

Suppose I have a function $f(x)$ defined as

$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      1 & g(x) < A\\
      0 & g(x) \geq A
   \end{cases}
$

Is it possible to define $f$ as a non piece wise function for $x,\; g(x),\; A \in \mathbb{R},\;> 0?$

For clarity, here's an example:

Suppose $A = 5,\;g(x) = x$

Can we formulate a non-piecewise version of the function:

$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      1 & x < 5\\
      0 & x \geq 5
   \end{cases}
$?

Comment: Could the person who downvoted explain what's wrong with my question?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @copper.hat, I've added an example, does this make it more clear?

Comment: Not really, I don't understand what you mean by 'formulate a non-piecewise version of the function'. The function is piecewise, so how can it not be??? Are you asking about notation?

Comment: I was hoping there existed a trick to make the function switch from 0 to 1 at a value without involving a piecewise.

Comment: Again, I don't know what you are asking. Once the function is defined it is defined. Are you asking if you can find a 'nearby' function that is continuous?

Comment: An equivalent function on $x>0$, yes

Comment: Sorry, I really am not following what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like

\begin{equation}
f(x)=\frac{1+\text{sgn}(A-g(x))-[g(x)=A]}{2}
\end{equation}
where $[g(x)=A]$ is a logic function having a value of 1 when the equation is true and a value of 0 when it is false.

Comment: This answers my question, thanks! One question though: If $[g(x)=A]$ is 1 when true, 0 when false, why wouldn't $f(x) = [g(x) < A]$ work?

Comment: You are absolutely correct. The logic function approach did not even occur to me until I had to figure out how to get rid of the unwanted $\frac{1}{2}$ term which popped up when $g(x)=A$. So your answer is best.

Comment: Great, cheers :)